# Exception while opening facebook login android

Tags: android, facebook

I'm making an android application with facebook login. I'm calling the facebook login by following code in my Activity.

```
Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

          // callback when session changes state
          @Override
          public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened()) {

              // make request to the /me API
              Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                // callback after Graph API response with user object
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                  if (user != null) {
                    //TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
                    //welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");
                  }
                }
              });
            }
          }
        });
```

But I get following exception when it tries to open the facebook login page getting this exception:

```
11-25 15:00:23.081: E/ActivityThread(30199): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
11-25 15:00:44.871: E/AndroidRuntime(30199): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-25 15:00:44.871: E/AndroidRuntime(30199): java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: com.facebook.android.R$layout.com_facebook_login_activity_layout
11-25 15:00:44.871: E/AndroidRuntime(30199):    at com.facebook.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:57)
11-25 15:00:44.871: E/AndroidRuntime(30199):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
11-25 15:00:44.871: E/AndroidRuntime(30199):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
11-25 15:00:44.871: E/AndroidRuntime(30199):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
11-25 15:00:44.871: E/AndroidRuntime(30199):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
11-25 15:00:44.871: E/AndroidRuntime(30199):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
11-25 15:00:44.871: E/AndroidRuntime(30199):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
11-25 15:00:44.871: E/AndroidRuntime(30199):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-25 15:00:44.871: E/AndroidRuntime(30199):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
11-25 15:00:44.871: E/AndroidRuntime(30199):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
11-25 15:00:44.871: E/AndroidRuntime(30199):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-25 15:00:44.871: E/AndroidRuntime(30199):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-25 15:00:44.871: E/AndroidRuntime(30199):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
11-25 15:00:44.871: E/AndroidRuntime(30199):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
11-25 15:00:44.871: E/AndroidRuntime(30199):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```